# How to read/change the log directory in Kohana 3.1?

Tags: kohana-3

In Kohana 2.x, there was a `$file = Kohana::log_directory();` which would get or set the directory based on parameters sent.

How to get the similar effect under Kohana 3.1?
I want to read the path of log directory and change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change it in bootstrap:

```
Kohana::$log->attach(new Log_File(APPPATH.'logs'));
```

Comment: I want to read the log path in my code... How can I achieve it?

Comment: You can't by default. You can extend Kohana_Log_File with Log_File on application level, adding a getter method which'll return you the directory. But still you won't be able to get to the Log_File writer being attached in the bootstrap without manually making a reference to it (Kohana_Log doesn't provide a way to iterate over attached writers without extending it).

Comment: we can't ask it to save to a particular file, isn't it? :(